# Quaternion rotation for gyroscope frame-of-reference conversion in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, vector, quaternions

I'm almost able to control the movement of an object in 2D space in Unity3D (similar to a cursor's movement), using raw gyroscope data from Thalmic's Myo armband.

I was trying to transform the gyroscope data from its own axes/frame of reference to the world frame of reference through a series of rotations and transformations.

Everything compiles except for a single error, and when this error is ignored, the object moves as the gyro rotates, but the final x-/y-coordinates are skewed in the wrong directions.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but my **[general approach](https://github.com/thalmiclabs/myo-mouse/blob/master/MouseMover.cpp)** would be to:

> 1. Obtain gyroscope Vector
> 2. Rotate it by orientation Quaternion (from accelerometer) to align it
>      to world space
> 3. Get normalized Quaternion that rotates the right vector
> 4. Rotate aligned Vector from (2) by this Quaternion to get a compensated Vector (-z) component of Vector from (2) and (y)
>          component of compensated Vector from (4) will give the desired dx
>          and dy values

Here is my approach:
Call the conversion function, input gyro data, current orientation and xDirection (whether the band is facing the wrist or reversed):

```
Vector2 dxdy = gyroConversion (thalmicMyo.gyroscope, myo.transform.rotation, thalmicMyo.xDirection);

transform.Translate (dxdy [0], dxdy [1], 0, Space.World);
```

The gyroConversion function:

```
Vector2 gyroConversion (Vector3 gyroData, Quaternion orientation, object xdir) {

    // Convert gyro data from the gyroscope's frame of reference to the world frame of reference.

    // Rotate gyroData by orientation quaternion.
    Vector3 gyroWorldData = orientation * gyroData;

    // Check which direction the armband is facing.
    if (xdir.Equals(Thalmic.Myo.XDirection.TowardWrist)) {
        Vector3 forwardSource = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
    }

    else {
        Vector3 forwardSource = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
    }

    Vector3 right = Vector3.Cross(forward, new Vector3 (0, 0, -1));
    Vector3 up = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);

    Quaternion yQuat = Quaternion.FromToRotation(right, up);

    float m = Mathf.Sqrt(yQuat.w * yQuat.w +
        yQuat.x * yQuat.x +
        yQuat.y * yQuat.y +
        yQuat.z * yQuat.z);

     yCompNorm = new Quaternion (yQuat.w / m, yQuat.x / m, yQuat.y / m, yQuat.z / m);

    Vector3 gyroCompensated = yCompNorm * gyroWorldData;

    Vector2 coordinates = new Vector2 (-gyroWorldData.z, gyroCompensated.y);

    return coordinates; }
```

Note: forwardSource is causing an error telling me that it 'doesn't exist in the current context', but when a single forwardSource definition exists instead of the if-else pair, it works fine and that's how I know the desired object is actually moving, just really weirdly. It seems like my left-right movements on the gyroscope are producing an up-down movement in Unity.

It's likely a problem with the rotations, but I don't see where.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my left-right movements on the gyroscope are producing an up-down movement in Unity.

Not exactly sure if this is the problem but the gyro `Input.gyro.attitude` sensor value is returned in *Right-Handed coordinates* while Unity uses the *Left-Handed coordinates* system. You need to convert the Gyro(Right-Handed coordinates) to Left-Handed coordinates before trying to use it to move an Object.

```
private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
{
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```

...

```
Quaternion convertedValue = GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude);
```

Now, you can use the `convertedValue`  variable for your other calculations or to move an object/camera.